# sql count / group by / zero

Tags: sql, count

Yes, there must be dozens of similar questions out there and I have tried literally 20 or 30 permutations, but I am still stumped.  Here is the simplest reduction:

```
select MyMethodNbr, count(*) from MyDB 
where MyMethodNbr in (33, 57, 150, 160, 200, 240)
group by MyMethodNbr 
order by MyMethodNbr ASC
```

Some items in MyMethodNbr list do not exist in the table, but I want to convert the nulls into zeros.  I can only get a table with non-zero counts.

Comment: which dbms oracle or mysql or sql server? if 33 doesn't exists, do you want zero against this value?

Comment: MS SQL.  Yes, if 33 doesn't exist, I want a zero count.  That's the problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a `left join`.  Here is typical syntax:

```
select n.n as MyMethodNbr, count(MyDB.MyMethodNbr) as num
from (select 33 as n union all select 57 union all select 150 union all select 160 union all
      select 200 union all select 240
     ) n left join
     MyDB 
     on MyDB.MyMethodNbr = n.n
group by n.n 
order by num ASC;
```

In some databases, you would need `from dual` or a similar construct to create the list of numbers.

Comment: Hmmm... What if my list is 100 items?  This seems a bit bulky.  In my original version, I was using a left join with another table that contains all the items in the "IN" list but also other items that I am not interested in.

Comment: @nas . . . You would need to generate the list somehow.  Excel can be useful for that.  Or, if the list is based on another query, then use that query.

Answer (score -1):

```
select ISNULL(MyMethodNbr,0), count(*) from MyDB 
where MyMethodNbr in (33, 57, 150, 160, 200, 240)
group by MyMethodNbr 
order by MyMethodNbr ASC
```